# Migrating from SQLite to Room: Migration didn't properly handle table

Tags: android, database, database-migration, android-room

So I was using the SQLite database and now I decided to migrate it to Room, without changing it. This is what my room model looks like

```
@Entity(tableName = "documents")
data class Document(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val docID: Int,
    val path: String,
    val filename: String,
    val dateCreated: Long = MAX_VALUE,
)
```

and this is the query I was using to create the table BEFORE room:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS documents (docID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, path TEXT NOT NULL unique, filename TEXT NOT NULL, dateCreated LONG DEFAULT MAX_VALUE)"
```

also, I created a new migration to the final version of the database, which uses the room, which I left empty because I don't wanna change anything in the table.

```
private val MIGRATION_9_10: Migration = object : Migration(9, 10) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {

    }
}
```

so when I finally run it on the device, which had the previous (9) version of the database, an exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: documents.
```

```
Expected: TableInfo{name='documents', columns={path=Column{name='path', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, filename=Column{name='filename', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, dataCreated=Column{name='dataCreated', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, docID=Column{name='docID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

Found: TableInfo{name='documents', columns={path=Column{name='path', type='STRING', affinity='1', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, filename=Column{name='filename', type='STRING', affinity='1', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, dataCreated=Column{name='dataCreated', type='LONG', affinity='1', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='9223372036854775807'}, docID=Column{name='docID', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

there are differences between the types of the path and filename fields, which are expected to be **TEXT**, but actually are **STRING** and also the type of dateCreated, which is expected to be **INTEGER** but is actually **LONG**. The interesting part for me is that dateCreated was of type long before and is still of type long. I tried adding a migration, which is as follows:

```
private val MIGRATION_9_10: Migration = object : Migration(9, 10) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        val tableDocumentsTemp = "documents_temp"
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE documents RENAME TO $tableDocumentsTemp")
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE documents (docId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, path STRING NOT NULL, filename STRING NOT NULL, dateCreated LONG DEFAULT $MAX_VALUE)")
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO documents (docId, path, filename, dateCreated) SELECT docId, path, filename, dateCreated FROM $tableDocumentsTemp")
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE $tableDocumentsTemp")
        }
    }
}
```

but this makes no difference.

Anybody has any ideas on how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write room database migration code, you have to use TEXT for String and INTEGER for long data type.

```
private val MIGRATION_9_10: Migration = object : Migration(9, 10) {
override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
    val tableDocumentsTemp = "documents_temp"
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE $tableDocumentsTemp (docId INTEGER NOT NULL, path TEXT NOT NULL, filename TEXT NOT NULL, dateCreated INTEGER DEFAULT $MAX_VALUE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(docId))")
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO $tableDocumentsTemp (docId, path, filename, dateCreated) SELECT docId, path, filename, dateCreated FROM documents")
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE documents")
    database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE $tableDocumentsTemp RENAME TO documents")
    }
 }
}
```